# How do I re-use a ByteBuffer to write several 512-byte chunks to a socket?

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer

Here's what I mean:

```
put 512 bytes
SocketChannel#write(this data)
start at the beginning and put 512 bytes again
rinse & repeat
```

I'm still trying to grasp ByteBuffers and I've tried using `ByteBuffer#reset()` but I always get an InvalidMarkException, even though this seems to be the correct solution (unless I'm wrong which I wouldn't be surprised!)

Thanks!

Edit:  Specifically, I'm trying to accomplish this same effect, except I want to send it in 512-byte chunks instead of in bulk.  http://privatepaste.com/1fb0e6df07

Answer (score 5):

No, `reset()` isn't the correct method. It's used to "roll back" streams or buffers, and not all of them support it (and it's not very useful in most cases). From the javadoc:

> Resets this buffer's position to the previously-marked position.

You can use the `clear()` method to clear out the buffer completely (i.e. set the position to zero and start writing more data in it).

Comment: Where does it say that not all ByteBuffers support reset()? Are you getting confused with InputStream.reset()?

Comment: @EJP indeed I was thinking about InputStreams. He was getting an InvalidMarkException because he hadn't set the mark.

Comment: Here's the weird thing.  I have tried this:  `in.flip() ... channel.write(in) ... in.clear()` already as well with no luck.

Comment: @connergdavis Post some of your actual code to see what's happening. Are you using blocking or non-blocking mode?

Comment: @Kayaman Admittedly I've spent the best part of the past hour trying to just send it all as one buffer.  This works just fine, but the only issue is that it seems to progressively eat my CPU all the way up to 100% if I let it send the data all as one big piece... which is, of course, bad.  I'm in blocking mode, it's a simple thread-per-client model. 

Here's what I have where I'm encountering this problem.  http://privatepaste.com/1fb0e6df07  Note that elsewhere, the buffer is returned, flipped, and the data is sent to the channel normally.

Comment: Did you try just flipping the buffer again?